# What is the bottom left number in tmux status bar?

Tags: terminal, tmux

[image: tmux status bar]

Cannot figure it out what is the `[3]` number.

Comment: That should be your buffer number? Can you see it listed with the `:ls` command?

Comment: Thaks! That must be it. I can see it with the :ls command

Comment: If, like me, you are used to have only one tmux session with many windows in it,  and therefore you don't really need that number, you can hide it with `set -g status-left ''`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the Tmux session name. You can [rename it](https://superuser.com/a/428025) using:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>

or

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>

To list the sessions, do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> and write `ls` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>.

By default, the session number is displayed.

Comment: The `[3]` should not be the session number but the vim buffer with the session. The `0:bash*` should be the Tmux session name.

Comment: @RedX I guess you're missing the point here, confusing tab names with session names. Tmux can have multiple sessions (e.g. `tmux` started in multiple tabs of some terminal emulator). Each session has a name (by default the zero-indexed id). Each session can have tabs–which contain the tab id and the started app by default (e.g. `4:vim`). Tabs can be renamed (`CTRL + B, ,`) and sessions can be renamed (like I pointed out in the answer). In this screenshot VIM has nothing to do with `tmux`, since `vim` is not even started. It's just a `bash` process. Hope I clarified the things out a little. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's the tmux session name.

That indicates you have three tmux sessions opened.

You can attach a terminal to a session using:

```
tmux attach
```

**Edit**

Active sessions can be discovered using:

```
tmux list-sessions
```

To close propperly a session:

```
tmux kill-session <session_name>
```

Comment: As @Ionică Bizău has said it's the session name. Thanks Ionică Bizău.